# Creating a simple todo list in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a simple todo list using expressJS. right now I just want to display some hardcoded todos that I have. But I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner to this and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

**I have done npm init and npm install express beforehand for the folder**

my code -

**server.js file**

```
const express=require('express')
const srv=express();


srv.get('/todos',(req,res)=>{

    const todosroute=require('./routes/todos')
    srv.use('/todos',todosroute)
    res.send(todos)
})

srv.listen(2323)
```

**todos.js file**

```
const serv=require('express').Router()
let todos=[
    {name:"Eat Kiwi's", time:"12pm"},
    {name:"Clean the room", time:"1pm"},
    {name:"Wash the car", time:"3pm"},
    {name:"Go to NSIT", time:"5.30 pm"},

]
route.get('/',(req,res,)=>res.send(todos))
route.get('/:id',(req,res)=>res.send(todos[req.params.id]))
module.exports=route
```

If you can explain the mistake would be great!

I'm getting this error on url->**http://localhost:2323/todos

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 2323 routes todos
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And this error on url->http://localhost:2323/routes/todos

```
 This site can’t be reached
    localhost refused to connect.
    Search Google for localhost 2323 routes todos
    ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

file structure ->[![Ive just put route folder as a comment mentioned and put todos.js in it
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG3mD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG3mD.png)

**//SOLVED :D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see right away in your `todo.js` is that you are exporting `route` but using `serv` -

```
const serv=require('express').Router()
let todos=[
    {name:"Eat Kiwi's", time:"12pm"},
    {name:"Clean the room", time:"1pm"},
    {name:"Wash the car", time:"3pm"},
    {name:"Go to NSIT", time:"5.30 pm"},

]
route.get('/',(req,res,)=>res.send(todos))
route.get('/:id',(req,res)=>res.send(todos[req.params.id]))
module.exports=route
```

Change it to -

```
const route=require('express').Router()
    let todos=[
        {name:"Eat Kiwi's", time:"12pm"},
        {name:"Clean the room", time:"1pm"},
        {name:"Wash the car", time:"3pm"},
        {name:"Go to NSIT", time:"5.30 pm"},

    ]
    route.get('/',(req,res,)=>res.send(todos))
    route.get('/:id',(req,res)=>res.send(todos[req.params.id]))
    module.exports=route
```

For `server.js`, please try -

```
const express=require('express')
const srv=express();
const todosroute=require('./routes/todos');

srv.use('/todos',todosroute);

srv.listen(2323)
```

Comment: So...? I'm new and I didn't get your point. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: You are exporting `route` in your `todo.js` file. But you are making a reference of `require('express').Router()` in `serv`. Both should be same. Get the point? Please feel free to ask if not.

Comment: it still doesnt work. I got your point. I think something is wrong in my server.js file too. I don't understand the use and get function that i've written

Comment: Yes, seems so. Please take a try at the one I copied. Will explain if it works.

Comment: OK its working I was going to wrong url only todos not routes/todos

Comment: On trying `srv.use('/todos',todosroute);` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it!

Comment: What url are you trying?

Comment: Cool. What was the issue?

Comment: I doubted that : ). That's the reason I asked for url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change you code to the following:

**server.js file**

```
const express=require('express')
const srv=express();


srv.use('/todos',require('./routes/todos'))

srv.listen(2323)
```

**todos.js file**

```
const serv=require('express').Router()
let todos=[
    {name:"Eat Kiwi's", time:"12pm"},
    {name:"Clean the room", time:"1pm"},
    {name:"Wash the car", time:"3pm"},
    {name:"Go to NSIT", time:"5.30 pm"},

]
serv.get('/',(req,res,)=>res.send(todos))
serv.get('/:id',(req,res)=>res.send(todos[req.params.id]))
module.exports=serv
```

The problem in your server.js is that you are sending the `todos` variable which is described in another router. You should instead use the router you created for all the `/todos` routes

The problem in your todos.js file is that you are storing the router in `serv` constant but using the undefined `route` variable.

Comment: OK i got that, that route was being sent undefined.

Comment: This should have solved your problem however if there is anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: OK its working I was going to wrong url only todos not routes/todos

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it!